# Smarty templates containing inline curly brackets error

Tags: php, smarty, fatal-error, curly-braces

I have some code that I am working on that has inline values such as `{32,15}` for some JavaScript, for a client. However it always causes an fatal error, in these cases. Is there a way that I can escape the curly braces so that they do not set off any more fatal errors, and still not affect the JavaScript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put it inside [`{literal}...{/literal}`](https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl), like so:

```html
{literal}
<script>
(function() {
    alert("Hooray for curly braces!");
})();
</script>
{/literal}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `{ldelim}{rdelim}` tags in place of the curly braces themselves. This is useful if you need working Smarty tags within the escaped braces.

```
<script language="javascript">
   <!--
   function getPrompt() {ldelim}
      // js function here
   {rdelim}
   //-->
</script>
```

Source: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.ldelim.tpl

Answer (score 0):

Use the `{literal}` tag that smarty provides. That is the only method I know of.